# Como autenticar no Firebase através do Google usando Expo (react native)?

Tags: firebase, google, react-native, expo

Eu tenho uma aplicação web no firebase, mas estou usando ela no desenvolvimento de um aplicativo android/ios usando Expo. Desejo que a autenticação seja feita pelo Google, mas acontece que por ter sido criada como web, pede ID e chave secreta do cliente. A função está assim:

```
   async signInWithGoogleAsync() {
    try {
      const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: 'meuandroidID',
        iosClientId: 'meuIOSID',
        scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
      });

      if (result.type === 'success') {
        const { idToken, accessToken } = result;
        const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);
        firebase
        .auth()
        .signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("firebase cred err:", error);
        });
        // return result.accessToken;
      } else {
        // return { cancelled: true };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // return { error: true };
    }
   }
```

Então na hora que o usuário autentica, o ID enviado é android ou IOS, o que retorna o seguinte erro, dizendo que por não se tratar de um ID para web ele não é permitido:

```
[Error: {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid Idp Response: the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is MYID, which is not authorized to be used in the project with project_number: MYPROJECTNUMBER.","errors":[{"message":"Invalid Idp Response: the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is MYID, which is not authorized to be used in the project with project_number: MYPROJECTNUMBER.","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}]
```

Então, como faço para resolver esse problema e conseguir me autenticar com o Google no firebase Web usando Expo react native?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, fiz da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Simplesmente adicionei os ID's ali em "Adicionar IDs de cliente à..."